# Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим со словом «пара»

Tags: согласование

*Пара дней отдыха в хижине, несомненно, пошли (?) на пользу.*

Правильная ли форма глагола? Есть ли правило на этот счет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При наличии в составе подлежащего имеми существительного со значением определенного количества (*тройка, сотня, **пара*** и т. п.) сказуемое ставится в форме единственного числа: *Семерка велосипедистов устремилась вперед*, *Сотня ребят разбежалась во все стороны, **Пара** ботинок была куплена за бесценок*.

См.: [источник 1](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/197-soglasovanieskazuemogospodlegawim.html), [источник 2](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo).

Comment: Вы недочитали правило по своей ссылке.

Comment: @bypasser3  Вы имеете в виду, что статья не претендует на полноту изложения?